# {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} fail to work in my application

Tags: delphi

I have an win32 application built with runtime packages.  I have enable {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} in my .dpr file.  I assume the executable file should have the flag set.

I then test to allocate this memory:

```
var A, B: TBytes;

procedure TForm60.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(A, 1024*1024*1024);
  SetLength(B, 1024*1024*1024);
end;
```

and I get `Out of memory` error.  I also make sure the runtime memory for application was less than 100M.  It should be below 3GB limit.

My runtime environment is Windows 10 v1803, RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo release 3. The application use few third party .bpl.

I try a sample project and the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flags is working as expected.  Without `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` the above code fail with `Out of memory` and works with the flag set.

Is there any steps I misconfigure for my application?

Comment: It's a mistake to try to allocate such large blocks in a 32 bit process. Use a tool like process hacker or dumpbin to check your process pe flags

Comment: Thanks.  I try to use a loop (2500 iteration) to allocate 1M memory block.  I can allocate 2.5GB in total and it works.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the executable file should have the flag set.

Better check this with a tool like `vmmap` from sysinternals suite.

But memory fragmentation may not allow two 1GB sized blocks even when the app has 4GB addressable space. The largest free block below 2GB is usually a bit less than one GB, and above 2GB there is usually some small stuff preventing you from allocating *all* of it.

Note that there is some overhead in heap management - your 1 GB blocks would actually need 1GB plus a couple of bytes of free space.

Comment: I think I found out the reason.  I have a rc resource file, the binary size if about 50M.  If I remove the rc file from project or reduce the resource file size, it works.  Just wondering if this is a restriction of `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`?

Comment: No. It's not. The problem is not that there isn't enough memory space available. The problem is finding contiguous blocks that aren't already used.